# Ajax requests from xul not working in firefox 2

Tags: javascript, firefox, xul, httprequest

I'm working on a firefox extension and have been developing it in Firefox 3, I went to test it on Firefox 2 and for some reason, none of my HTTP requests is firing. The format of the requests are below (using prototype):

```
theResponse = function(response){
    //some code
}

new Ajax.Request(url,{
    method:'get',
    parameters : {url: currentURL},
    onSuccess: theResponse,
    onFailure: function(){ alert('Something went wrong...') }
});
```

I have been trying to find a solution but the closest thing I've found is something to do with cross-site HTTPrequests, anyone has any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Figured out the problem was to do with the way prototype performs HTTPrequests, switched to using jquery and no further problems ... well with HTTPrequests anyway.